# How to create a dynamic type based on a value with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm building a React component that would have a different HTML tag based on a property a user passed. Here's an example:

```js
interface Common {
    common?: number;
}

interface A extends Common {
    first?: string;
    second?: string;
    check: true;
}

interface B extends Common {
    third?: string;
    fourth?: string;
    check?: false;
}

type Test = A | B;
```

To test this, I'm expecting the following:

```js
// Success
let test: Test = {
    common: 1,
    check: true,
    first: "text"
}
// Success
let test: Test = {
    common: 1,
    check: false,
    third: "text"
}
// Fail
let test: Test = {
    common: 1,
    check: true,
    third: "text"
}
// Fail
let test: Test = {
    common: 1,
    check: false,
    first: "text"
}
```

All of that is working, the challenge is to get type B without passing a value to check at all, like such:

```js
let test: Test = {
    common: 1,
    first: "text", // should highlight an error because `check` is not passed
    third: "text",
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```js
// Attempt 1: is to include possible values
interface B extends Common {
    third?: string;
    fourth?: string;
    check?: false | null | undefined | never | unknown | void; // tried them all
}

// Attempt 2: is not to include at all. Still didn't work
interface B extends Common {
    third?: string;
    fourth?: string;
}
```

Comment: Why would it error? `test` obj conforms to to B interface.

Comment: Instead of `check?: false` you can do: `check: false,` to distinguish between those two interfaces.

Comment: @r3dst0rm
It will work regardless when you pass `true` or `false` to the `check`. But the problem that I'm facing is that I want to infer that's it is of type B when I don't even pass the value of `check`. I tried this: `check: false | undefined` as in the value is not passed so it's undefined. But it didn't work

Comment: What if you remove the check from B altogether and the way to distinguish between the two would be to see if the check exists or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `A | B` is inclusive OR, but you need [exclusive OR](https://timhwang21.gitbook.io/index/programming/typescript/xor-type). You can use [npm package `ts-xor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xor).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this statically. You need to use type guards, so you first have a Test type what is checked statically, but then you need to check it via guard to have the right typing:

```js
function isB(param: A | B): param is B {
  return (param as B).checked === false;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33566314)

Answer (score -1):

Since Check is common between the two interfaces. Why not

```
interface Common {
    common?: number;
    check?: boolean;
}


interface A extends Common {
    first?: string;
    second?: string;
}

interface B extends Common {
    third?: string;
    fourth?: string;
}

type Test = A | B;
```

Instead ?

Comment: It's required in `A` while it's not in `B`. You effectively removed `check` altogether. All his test cases are not working anymore.